# Are there authorization plugin support for RPMs?

Tags: centos, yum, centos-7, rpm

I'd like to restrict running some RPMs based on additional rules (on top of GPG). Is there a way to create a Authorization plugin for RPMs in CentOS 7+?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to disallow certain packages via yum with this command:

```
yum --exclude foo\* --exclude bar\*
```

For more information, check [this webpage](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-yum-disable-certain-packages-from-being-installed/).

Comment: I'm looking for more dynamic checks, not just static disallow.